# Django app - data processing on the server

Tags: python, django

I have some question about some django app.

Simple example:

On the server I'd like to run some program, which should display some value.
Example:

```
for(i in range(10)):
    print(10**i)
    sleep(1)
```

So value changes every 1 second without refreshing.
It could be some progress bar etc.

How to start with it? Celery is the good start? What should I look for?

Best regards!

Edit:
It could be somethink like progress bar etc.

For example only x% value on my page. 
And some data should be processed in the background.

You know what I mean?

Comment: Why are you using sleep? Sleep will just stop everything, stop all your execution for 1s

Comment: I am not using sleep, there will be some algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twisted which is a Python networking library.

From the documentation :

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor
timeout = 60.0 #specify interval over here in seconds

def doWork():
    #do whatever work you want to do here
    pass

rep_work = task.LoopingCall(doWork)
rep_work.start(timeout) # call every sixty seconds
reactor.run()
```